# Entity Framework returns incomplete xml data

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework, serialization

EntityFramework returns incomplete data for xml field.
I Serialize data and save this in an xml field in the db. The missing data is in the Images node value in the xml is also serialized a serilized object. The ecoding of the value happens when i serialze the field object.

**Where is my missing data from the Images -> Value field and why does it dissapear?**

This is what i have in my ms sql xml field:

```
<ArrayOfField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Field>
    <Key>Images</Key>
    <Value>&lt;ArrayOfImage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;Image&gt;
    &lt;Name&gt;Penguins.jpg&lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;Path&gt;~/Fileshare/Pages/6/Penguins.jpg&lt;/Path&gt;
    &lt;AltText&gt;Test&lt;/AltText&gt;
  &lt;/Image&gt;
  &lt;Image&gt;
    &lt;Name&gt;Tulips.jpg&lt;/Name&gt;
    &lt;Path&gt;~/Fileshare/Pages/6/Tulips.jpg&lt;/Path&gt;
    &lt;AltText&gt;Test&lt;/AltText&gt;
  &lt;/Image&gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfImage&gt;</Value>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Key>Test</Key>
    <Value>Test</Value>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Key>MyEditor</Key>
    <Value />
  </Field>
</ArrayOfField>
```

This is what EF returns:

```
<ArrayOfField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Field><Key>Images</Key><Value>&lt;ArrayOfImage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" /&gt;</Value></Field><Field><Key>Test</Key><Value>Test</Value></Field><Field><Key>MyEditor</Key><Value /></Field></ArrayOfField>
```

I get data from EntityFramework like this:

```
  public Item Get(int id)
        {
            using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                var item = context.Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
                return item;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you are looking at the item with the same id in both SQL and EF query? Because the sample you gave seems to be an ok formatted xml but with just an empty arrayOfImage, no children. So it's not like EF is trimming the xml inner text or something.

Comment: @dutzu Yes Im sure about that. None of my other items contains the Images node.

Comment: Do you have a helpful answer? Then accept it. Your question will be marked as answered and no longer will be listed in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @espvar if you have your answer, please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write a stored procedure to return the xml field data. For Entity Framework, you need to write something like following to get the full list of xml data

```
EntityCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "XXXX";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

using (EntityDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
          str = str + reader.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think either the data is lost during deserialization, or it's a mistake due to fatigue on your part (i mean, you might be looking at a different entity when comparing and you think there is something wrong).

Either way, an alternative to rule out the serialization issue is to save it serialized as something else or avoid having an xml in an xml (even though there shouldn't be any problem) by just adding the ArrayOfImages as a class member and not just another key/value pair in your array.